# Advoid many try-catch blog when parse json

Tags: android, json, exception

I try get data from Facebook sdk:

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = object.getString("name");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String profile = null;
    try {
        profile = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String cover = null;
    try {
        cover = object.getJSONObject("cover").getString("source");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String email = null;
    try {
        email = object.getString("email");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String gender = null;
    try {
        gender = object.getString("gender");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String birthday = null;
    try {
        birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new SessionManager(activity).storeUserInfo(name, profile, cover, email, gender, birthday);
}
```

It is very adverse because there are many field, each field can be null and each field need a try-cach blog.

I need a solution to present code clearer.

Comment: **each field can be null** ??? your catch occur when ``object.getString("key");`` return null, right ???

Comment: if there is no "key", it will throw a exception so that I need catch it to advoid  pass other field

Comment: no, it throw a exception

Comment: Are you not able to use Gson or Jackson? This is already a solved problem.

Comment: @mdtuyen ok, check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you only want to remove the try catch block, use "opt" to replace "get"
(eg. `optInt(Key)`, `optString(Key)` ..)

Please care that "opt" will return null if the key is not exist, it may case many null pointer exception without checking.

Comment: The OP already has nulls in many cases (whether or not such is intended), so using optXYZ is the most direct approach to avoid the gets-with-exceptions on the individual keys.

Comment: I think the better in this case is use gson.

Answer (score 3):

OK, you can check key is exists or not by call `object.has("key")` like this:

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
    String name = "", profile = "", cover = "", email = "", gender = "", birthday = "";
    try {
        if (object.has("name")){
            name = object.getString("name");
        }
        if (object.has("picture")){
            profile = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
        }
        if (object.has("cover")){
            cover = object.getJSONObject("cover").getString("source");
        }
        if (object.has("email")){
            email = object.getString("email");
        }
        if (object.has("gender")){
            gender = object.getString("gender");
        }
        if (object.has("birthday")){
            birthday = object.getString("birthday");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new SessionManager(activity).storeUserInfo(name, profile, cover, email, gender, birthday);
}
```

Comment: Says object.getString("name") throws NPE, you will never able to reach the rest of the values. right?

Comment: It is clearer but still long, I will consider it as an option.

Comment: ``object.has("name")`` is check ``name`` is exists or not, if not, ``name = object.getString("name");`` will never call, so how to NPE occur @Jiyeh

Comment: yeah but what if `.getJSONObject("data")` throws null, you have to check that too

Comment: @meda yup, but in this case function ``onCompleted`` already have ``object`` is a ``JSONObject`` , we no need ``.getJSONObject("data")`` again.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it this way:

```
String value = object.has(key) && !object.isNull(key) ? object.getString(key) : null;
```

One line, cleaner and easier~ :)

Comment: I would rather 'write a method' if using that format of code more than .. once.

Comment: Yea you could! it makes it much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

**Are all your fields compulsory?**
You can do this:

```
try{
   name = object.getString("name");
   ... // more methods here
   new SessionManager(activity).storeUserInfo(name, profile, cover, email, gender, birthday);
}catch(JSONException e){
  e.printStackTrace( );
}
```

This way, you will reach `SessionManager` only when you have retrieved all the fields. Even if a single field is missing, you'll go straight to the `catch` block.

**Else:**

```
public String getString(JSONObject obj,String key,String defVal){
    if( obj.has(key) )
        return obj.getString( key );
    return defVal; 
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

`name = getString(json,"name","UNDEFINED");`

Comment: what happen if keyword "email" missing, We can't get gender and birthday.

Answer (score 1):

add all the syntax in one try block If any one syntax have exception than go in catch....

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) { String name = null; try { name = object.getString("name"); String profile = null; profile = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url"); String cover = null; cover = object.getJSONObject("cover").getString("source"); String email = null; email = object.getString("email"); String gender = null; gender = object.getString("gender"); String birthday = null; birthday = object.getString("birthday"); } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } new SessionManager(activity).storeUserInfo(name, profile, cover, email, gender, birthday); }
```

Comment: (Indent 4 spaces for code, and avoid lines with '---' unless wanting to create headers. You can go back in and add newlines.)

Comment: what happen if keyword "email" missing, We can't get gender and birthday.